# (Java)Having trouble converting to Hexadecimal

Tags: java, binary, hex, octal

My assignment is: Write an application that prints a table of the binary, octal, and hexadecimal equivalents of the decimal numbers
in the range 1 through 256. If you are not familiar with these number systems research online the needed information  Place the results in a JOptionPane.showMesaageDialog.

My code currently is:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prog3_22
{
public static void main (String args[])
{

int a;
int b;
int c;

String billybob = "Decimal "+"\tBinary"+"\tOctal "+"\tHex",binary,oct,hex;

for(int x=1;x<=256;x++)
{
    binary="";oct="";hex="";
    c=x;
    a=x;
    b=x;
    while (c>0)
    {
        int rem= c %2;
        binary=rem+binary;
        c=c/2;
    }//end while
    while (b>0)
    {
        int rem= h%16;
        hex=rem+hex;
        b=b/16;
    }
    while (a>0)
    {
        int rem= a%8;
        oct=rem+oct;
        a=a/8;
    }


billybob+="\n" +x+ "\t"+binary+"\t"+oct+"\t"+hex+"\t";
}//end for



JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea (10,40);
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane (outputArea);
outputArea.setText(billybob);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,scroller,null,
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
    }
```

It mostly works except for the Hex column which only shows up as 0. I'm not sure how to fix it so any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Could we see a sample of the output?

Comment: Wasn't sure how else to put this all in, sorry. https://docs.google.com/document/d/10mARN16lpTORfO2XtuppO-cKLQruJydJ02GCYGeOPVE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You have a random reference to h%16, which as far as I can tell is not assigned. I think you intended it to read as b%16. I'm not sure how your code is compiling with this error.

With this fix, I get hex = 100 when x = 256.

Comment: There is still a second error, but something should remain to do.

Comment: When I make this change, I get digits under the hex column but I don't believe the output is correct. Output: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sKIFKRhOBvdY0lu3BHaow8iVLsg7ZsBZEhsrdpF_qVE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is your system supposed to be converting numbers to letters? It doesn't look like you have anything in place to handle that. In the case of x = 31, hex = 1F, according to [this converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter).